# ACF IMG returns ID not URL when in archive.php

Tags: php, wordpress, image, archive, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site and have a simple div with a background image in `footer.php` being called from ACF options field like so:

```
<div id="footer" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('footer_background', 'options'); ?>');">
```

This works perfectly on all my pages and templates. However, when going into a blog category (from the categories widget in the blog page) which is calling `archive.php` it converts the URL to the image ID and outputs `'85'` rather than the URL.

I've tried removing all code from archive.php except the header and footer calls incase I had something in there but still no luck. The ACF field is definitely set to 'url' hence it works everywhere else.

Any ideas why it converts to ID on the `archive.php` page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and I found no fix for the plugin, but I solved the situation by making a conditional statement to check if the page was a tag archive and then retrieve the attachment URL by the returned ID.

```
if (is_tag()) {
    $imgUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_field('image', 'option') );
    } else {
        $img = get_field('image', 'option');
        $imgUrl = $img['url'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Mine was because I removed an old field and created it again with the same name on another group.

What happened is that the old ACF key remained unchanged. This very SO question was [mentioned at ACF forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/image-returns-id-no-matter-what-return-value-is-set/) where I found the hint about the problem:

> If an image field is always returning the image ID rather than another value as set in the field setting then this is a symptom of a missing or incorrect field_key in the database

My old stored values all were wrong, I had to updated them to `field_60665667aa3d3` and the URL return started working again.

[image: database schema]